# не выводится сообщение

Tags: python, sqlite, бот, discord, discord.py

написал вот такой вот вывод предупреждений. Но не выводиться, ошибок нету

```
async def __warn(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        print('low')
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            await ctx.send (f"""Количество предупреждений **{ctx.author}**: **{cursor.execute('SELECT warn FROM users WHERE id = {}'.format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :rage:**""")
        ))
    else:
        print ('d')
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Количество предупреждений **{member}**: **{cursor.execute('SELECT warn FROM users WHERE id = {}'.format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]} :rage:**"""
        ))
```

Comment: декоратор не забыли накинуть?

Comment: нет. не забыл...

Comment: await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(color = random.randint(0, 0xffffff)).add_field(name="\u200b",
            value=f"123", inline=False))

там сверху всё равно маленький пробел будет. name убрать уже нельзя

Answer (score 0):

Делайте вот так:

```
await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(color = random.randint(0, 0xffffff)).add_field(name="\u200b", value=f"123", inline=False))
```

там сверху всё равно маленький пробел будет. name убрать уже нельзя

- \u200b - отвечает за пустую строку, просто пустой её оставить нельзя.
- color = random.randint(0, 0xffffff) - генерирует рандомный цвет

Под ваш код

```
async def __warn(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        print('low')
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(color = random.randint(0, 0xffffff)).add_field(name="Количество предупреждений **{ctx.author}**", value=f"**{cursor.execute('SELECT warn FROM users WHERE id = {}'.format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :rage:**", inline=False))

    else:
        print ('d')
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(color = random.randint(0, 0xffffff)).add_field(name="Количество предупреждений **{member}**", value=f"**{cursor.execute('SELECT warn FROM users WHERE id = {}'.format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]} :rage:**", inline=False))
```